# Which weapons count as a shotgun in Fallout Shelter?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I've got this objective:

> Equip 2 Dwellers with a Shotgun

I tried equipping with *Enhanced Sawed-Off Shotgun*, *Sawed-Off Shotgun* and *Rusty Combat Shotgun*, but none of those work. For the *Equip n Dwellers with a weapon* objectives, it's enough to switch out the weapon for a fists and back to the weapon, but here that doesn't seem to work.

Which weapon do I need to use to fulfill this objective?

Comment: Some of the objectives require that the dweller has never done the thing before.  Try giving a shotgun to someone who has never had a shotgun.

Comment: @Jason I tried most of my 54 dwellers. But I am at a point were all of them either has a Shotgun or a Laser Pistol or an Enhanced Hunting Rifle. Everyone has at least a minimum damage of 5 weapon. I'm not sure who has not had a Shotgun, but I also tried the most recent lunchbox dweller who came without a gun, and it also didn't work.

Comment: None of the listed weapons are shotguns. See my answer for a list of shotguns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here's a partial list of weapons](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_Shelter_weapons) and their type.

As Jason Berkan commented, the fastest way to complete that kind of objective is to find a dweller without the type of weapon required and equip them with one. If you don't have a spare weapon of the type needed in your inventory, unequip one from a dweller with a weapon of that type, find a dweller without that type of weapon and give them the weapon.

In your case, the type is a shotgun but this applies to any objective requiring to equip an armor or weapon type. Also, beware that Sawed-Off Shotgun and Combat Shotgun are types of their own.

Shotguns are

1. Rusty shotgun
2. Shotgun
3. Enhanced shotgun
4. Hardened shotgun
5. Double-barrel shotgun
6. Farmer's Daughter